# Get selected option html when using parent form (not document) using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HMTL form, that it's repeated multiple times on a webpage, in order to prevent to target every specific field name, of every form, i'm doing a general-use javascript script that detects where was triggered and obtain the values of the fields (of that specific form traversing from it) in order to send it to another server using ajax call. The problem is that I can't find a way to obtain a selected item of a select dropdown list.

Since it's a general-use script I can't use ID value.

```js
function sendForm(reference){
  const form = reference.closest('form');
  var elements = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var name = elements.namedItem('name').value;
  var mail = encodeURIComponent(elements.namedItem('email').value);
  // Here I don't know how to get the selected item from the option group)
  var program = elements.namedItem('program').value;  // (it doesn't work);
  console.log(name)
  console.log(mail)
  /*
    Ajax Stuff that is already solved  and not needed to show the point
  */
}
```

```html
<form id="my-form" data-origin="form-1" action="">
  <input placeholder="Name*" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email*" name="email" id="mail" required>
  <select class="form-control" name="program" required>
    <option name="programa" value="">- Select -</option>           
    <option value="LCP">First choice</option>
    <option value="LSP">Seccond choice</option>
    <option value="LAE">Third choice</option>
    <option value="LD">Fourth choice</option>
   </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="sendForm(this)" class="btn">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You've abstracted your JavaScript function so that you can apply the same function to multiple `<form>` elements, but you're specifying `elements.namedItem('nombre')`, rather than collecting the form-elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`...) and retrieving values. Are you limiting the generality deliberately or is this an in-development function that will be further abstracted later?

Comment: David, as you mention, I want to use the same function to handle several forms, I try to get all values using namedItem(NameAtribute) because all of the forms, have the same attribute name, nonetheless I can't find a way to get the value from a selected option  of an optiongroup.

Comment: `elements` doesn't include your `<select>` item.

Comment: Now I get it user1599011, Ill post the complete answer in a minute

Answer (score 1):

`var programa = document.getElementById('program').value;` should work, as long as the `<select>` only allows one option to be selected.

Comment: I can't use getElementById because there could be 10 or more forms and every 1 should have a specific Id, since is a general porpouse script, it should be able to handle every form (without needed to focus to every id)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the MDN documentation for the [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement), you can see that the `value` property will be the value of the selected option (or the first selected option in case of a `<select multiple>` element).

Also, the `HTMLFormElement` has an `elements` property (read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)) which returns a collection of all the form controls in the form (not just inputs, but also `<select>` elements which is what you need instead of `getElementsByTagName` on the form.

So in your code, you could do:

```
const form = reference.closest('form');
const program = form.elements.namedItem('program').value;
```

Sidenote: if you're going to use `const` for one variable, stop using `var`. It's a misfeature.